# Search and copy files from all directories

Tags: bash

I have a main directory with lots of sub-directories. I would like to search for a particular file format (for example: *_hist.log) and copy to a new folder. How can I do this in bash?

Comment: `find` + `-exec` + `cp`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Normally, this is done with the `find` command. However, there is a way to get the list of files 100% inside of bash:

```
shopt -s globstar
cp **/*_hist.log /wherever/you/want/to/copy/them
```

From https://www.gnu.org/software/bash/manual/html_node/The-Shopt-Builtin.html:

> `globstar`
>
> If set, the pattern ‘**’ used in a filename expansion context will match all files and zero or more directories and subdirectories. If the pattern is followed by a ‘/’, only directories and subdirectories match.